# ActionCable not connecting during capybara-webkit feature spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, capybara, capybara-webkit, actioncable

I have a problem using actioncable with feature specs using Capybara-webkit. Actioncable is working perfectly on my development server, but when testing the javascript cant seem to connect.

This is the output from the javascript console which is running during my feature spec

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:32789/cable' failed: Unexpected response code: 200
```

This is the output of my `test.log` at that moment

```
GET     "/cable"  for 127.0.0.1  at 2017-01-26 13:33:23 +0000
GET     "/cable/"  for 127.0.0.1  at 2017-01-26 13:33:23 +0000
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
```

Its strange because it seems like Its connecting fine according to the log, but the javascript throws an error and stops executing... Also how is `200` an error code? Doesn't `200` status code always mean `OK`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: WebSocket server should respond with `101 Switching Protocols`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default server used by Capybara is :webrick which doesn't support testing ActionCable (it will be changing whenever Capybara 3.0 releases).  To switch it to using puma which will support testing with ActionCable you can specify `Capybara.server = :puma` as part of your Capybara configuration.

Comment: make sure to require 'puma', and add it your gems file or gemspec

Answer (score 0):

2023, Rails 7.0.4, capybara 3.39.0, Turbo::StreamsChannel works well with selenium webdriver.

Problem seems to be solved from capybara.

My config, in `rails_helper` is:

```
  config.before(:each, type: :system) do
    driven_by :selenium, using: :headless_chrome, screen_size: [1200, 600]
  end
```